# Displaying data from Blade model using the click function

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel-5.4

I am using the button to display the details of the particular person using the data-toggle="modal" but the button is not performing any action. When I click the button I am not able to display any details of the user.

Route:

```
Route::get('document', 'PatientController@show');
```

Controller:

```
public function show()
    {
        $patient_user=patient_user::all();
        return view('document')->with('patient_user',$patient_user);
    }
```

View:

```
<form id="myForm" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-full-width" id="sample_1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Patient ID</th>
                        <th>Patient Name</th>
                        <th>Full Name</th>
                        <th>DOB</th>
                        <th>Ref. Name</th>
                        <th>Payment</th>
                        <th>Doc Status</th>
                        <th>Appointment</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach($patient_user as $key=>$row)
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$row->patient_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{$row->patient_firstname}}</td>
                        <td>{{$row->patient_firstname}} {{$row->patient_lastname}}</td>
                        <td>{{$row->dob}}</td>
                        <td>{{$row->refering_physician_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$row->dob}} </td>
                        <td>{{$row->dob}}</td>
                        <td>{{$row->app_date}}</td>
                        <td class="center">
                            <div class="visible-md visible-lg hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                                <a href='{{ url("Trail/{$row->patient_id}") }}' class="btn btn-xs btn-teal tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                <a href='#' data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs btn-green tooltips" data-id="{{ $row->patient_id}}" data-target="static" onclick="pat_det{{ $row->patient_id }}" data-placement="top" data-original-title="View" id="pat_det"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                                <a href='{{ url("destroy/{$row->patient_id}") }}' class="btn btn-xs btn-bricky tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Remove"><i class="fa fa-times fa fa-white"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="static" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" style="display: none;">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4><i>Patient Details</i></h4> 
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-6">First Name</div>
                    <div class="col-md-5" id="fname"> {{ $row->patient_firstname}} </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-6">Middle Name</div>
                    <div class="col-md-5" id="mname"> {{ $row->middle_name}} </div>
                </div>
                 <br>
                 <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-6">Last Name</div>
                    <div class="col-md-5" id="lname"> {{ $row->patient_lastname}} </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#static').on('show', function(e) 
    {
                e.preventDefault();
                var link     = e.relatedTarget(),
                modal    = $(this),
                patient_firstname = link.data("patient_firstname"),
                middle_name = link.data(middle_name),
                patient_lastname = link.data("patient_lastname"),

                modal.find("#fname").val(patient_firstname);
                modal.find("#mname").val(middle_name);
                modal.find("#lname").val(patient_lastname);

    });
</script>
```

where #static is my modal Id and the value within find are the id's of the particular fields and val are the database values.

Comment: Hi, did you checked you find the value of  "patient_firstname", "middle_name", "patient_lastname" name when modal is the show?

Comment: You're using the jQuery [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function. However you do not have those `data-*` attributes set anywhere.

Comment: it is not showing anything the button itself is not performing any action @RenishKhunt

Comment: How to set the attributes..? @PeterM

Comment: You need to change your opening `<a>` tag and add `data-patient_firstname="{{$row->patient_firstname}}"` etc.

Comment: all the attributes i need to change and add in the <a> tag..? @PeterM

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're requesting data from attributes that are not set.

```
patient_firstname = link.data("patient_firstname"),
```

The above part is trying to retrieve the value of the attribute `data-patient_firstname`. Since the original link does not have this attribute there won't be any data.

Change

```
<a href='#' data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs btn-green tooltips" data-id="{{ $row->patient_id}}" data-target="static" onclick="pat_det{{ $row->patient_id }}" data-placement="top" data-original-title="View" id="pat_det"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
```

Into

```
<a href='#' data-toggle="modal" 
data-patient_firstname="{{$row->patient_firstname}}" <-- do this for all requested vars
class="btn btn-xs btn-green tooltips" data-id="{{ $row->patient_id}}" data-target="static" onclick="pat_det{{ $row->patient_id }}" data-placement="top" data-original-title="View" id="pat_det"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
```

That way the `data-*` attributes will be availble.

Comment: i made the changes still the button is not performing any action if I click on the button it is constant only not giving any value or error. @Peter M

Comment: My guess is that you're using bootstrap 3.? Try using `$('#static').on('shown.bs.modal',function...` instead of `$('#static').on('show', function...`

Comment: sorry no still its not working the button is not performing any action its constant only@Peter M